# Unable to mount SD card

Tags: linux, mount, drm

I'm not sure this is a right forum to post this question. However,

I have this SD card I'm trying to mount on my linux machine. It always gives me

```
mount /dev/sdb mount/
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb

parted /dev/sdb 
Error: Error opening /dev/sdb: No medium found                            
Retry/Cancel?

ls /dev/sdb*
/dev/sdb
```

I'm pretty sure this has a file system since this is the SD card of my Nissan Leaf. I'm trying to convert the japanese text to English. As far as I know DRM prevents cloning, but it should not prevent me from reading. Am I missing something here.

EDIT
Tried exFat not seems working

```
lsblk /dev/sdb - give no output
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb - give no output
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the DRM section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Card_security) , specifically:

*DRM copy-protection*

*All cards incorporate DRM copy-protection. Roughly 10% of the storage capacity of an SD card is a "Protected Area" not available to the user, but is used by the on-card processor to verify the identity of an application program that it then allows to read protected content. The card prohibits other accesses, such as users trying to make copies of protected files.*

Basically, they're using the "secure" part of the Secure Digital format as it was intended so that only the authorized application (your specific NAV unit) can unlock the partitions of the card and read them. That's why you have to send them the Unit Code and Serial Number of your GPS to order a new card.

Answer (score 0):

The SD card might be formatted exFAT. Ubuntu and possibly other distros do not include exFAT drivers, but they are [easily added in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/370398/how-to-get-a-drive-formatted-with-exfat-working):

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils exfat-fuse
```

Reboot might be needed.

Other Linux distros have different exFAT installation procedures. The issue open software has with including that file system is that [exFAT is proprietary](https://www.maketecheasier.com/access-exfat-file-system-in-ubuntu/).

Comment: nope it did not work

Answer (score 0):

The device "/dev/sdb" is alwas present, also if there is no medium in it.
So if mount says "no medium found on /dev/sdb" ther is no medium in /dev/sdb.

I think you try to mount the wrong device.

Loog into your /var/log/messages while inserting the sdcard, then you see the right device

Comment: Nope. I dont think so. i have only one disk. sda. sdb shows when I connect the sd card. I confirmed this with the logs.